# Angular Material Design : Radio button group to be vertically aligned

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Below is the angular material code i am using to display radio buttons :

```
<div>
    <mat-radio-group>
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Transcription</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2">Summarization</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="3">Both</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

But this is displaying the radiobuttons horizontally. But i need them to be displayed vertically.

Answer (score 26):

You can use CSS to get this done, add a class to your `mat-radio-group` where you can use:

- `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`
- or `display: grid;`
- or `display: inline-grid;`

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div>
    <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Transcription</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2">Summarization</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="3">Both</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
.example-radio-group {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column;
  /* display: inline-grid; */ 
  /* display: grid; */
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzybcw)

Comment: If you are using `@angular/material` simply add the attribute `fxLayout="column"` which is equivalent to the CSS class above.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a `<br>` tag after each `<mat-radio-button>`